# How to change a QLabel to a QLineEdit when mouse pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, qlineedit, qlabel

I am trying to create a custom class so that whenever a mouse press event occurs, a QLabel should change to a QLineEdit. So, after searching, I found this code on a Qt website. But, unfortunately, it is not working. A user who posted this question had accepted this code as working, but I am new to Qt, as well as Python, so I need some help.

```
class nameDisplay(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,buddyList,parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.buddyList = buddyList

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print 'mousePressEvent'
        self.buddyList.username.hide()
        self.buddyList.usernameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.buddyList)
        self.buddyList.usernameInput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 121, 20))
        self.buddyList.usernameInput.setText(self.buddyList.username.text())
        self.buddyList.usernameInput.selectAll()
        self.buddyList.usernameInput.show()
        self.connect(self.buddyList.usernameInput,QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"),self.editingFinish)

    def editingFinish(self):
        self.buddyList.usernameInput.hide()
        self.buddyList.username.show()
        self.buddyList.username.setText(self.buddyList.usernameInput.text())
```

**Update**:

The error I am getting is:

```
# Error: line 1: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 22, in <module>
# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) #
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See how to make a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get a `Qlabel` to switch over to a `QLineEdit`. Alternatively you can use `QLineEdit.setPlaceholderText()` to show some default text when the field is left empty. This may be another option for you to use (and will be way more simple).

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Make a custom label widget (mostly for its mousePressEvent)
class BuddyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, buddy, parent = None):
        super(BuddyLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.buddy = buddy

    # When it's clicked, hide itself and show its buddy
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.buddy.show()
        self.buddy.setFocus() # Set focus on buddy so user doesn't have to click again

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create ui
        self.myEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.myEdit.hide() # Hide line edit
        self.myEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.textEdited)
        self.myLabel = BuddyLabel(self.myEdit) # Create our custom label, and assign myEdit as its buddy
        self.myLabel.setText('Nothing has been entered')
        self.myLabel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed) # Change vertical size policy so they both match and you don't get popping when switching

        # Put them under a layout together
        hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.myLabel)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.myEdit)

        # Add a line edit with a place holder
        self.myEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.myEdit2.setPlaceholderText('Nothing has been entered')
        self.setFocus() # By default this line edit may have focus and the place holder won't show up on load, so focus on the widget

        # Create main layout
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(hLayout)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.myEdit2)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # Resize and show!
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.show()

    def textEdited(self):
        # If the input is left empty, revert back to the label showing
        if not self.myEdit.text():
            self.myEdit.hide()
            self.myLabel.show()

win = Window()
```

Comment: thank you for your reply it works exactly what i want. can you refer me any pyqt tutorials?

Comment: There's no "how to learn pyqt" tutorials that I know of. Just use Google a lot to search for examples.